# jQuery UI accordion replaces styling for unordered list?

Tags: jquery, css, list, accordion

I can't seem to figure out how to prevent the jQuery accordion from changing the css styling on my navigation on my webpage. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rAUg3/2/

The accordion makes my unordered list inside the .accordion div so long that it overflows, and also seems to remove or replace all css styling for the lists. I've tried adding the clearStyle true, and autoHeight false to no avail. Any suggestions?

Here's my jQuery so far:

```
$(function () {
    $(".accordion").accordion({
        active: false,
        clearStyle: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        collapsible: true
    });
});
```

Thank you for any and all help!!

Comment: your style is fully applied http://jsfiddle.net/rAUg3/4/

Answer (score 0):

you could just override the specific styles by adding `!important`

eg:

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: none !important;
}
```

Comment: or you could try `ul {
    list-style-type: none !important;
}` which will override accordion unordered list styles.